# Can we used tflite in ml.net?

Tags: c#, wpf, tensorflow, ml.net

I am trying to use the tflite model that I used in android project to run in WPF application. I have original h5 model. I tried to convert the original into ONNX model but I am not getting good result as the model was based on tensorflow.

Comment: maybe you can try [this](https://github.com/jackwish/tflite2onnx)

Comment: I tried your suggestion but output is not same as with tflite for some reason.